# Деление над большими числами

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Подскажите, плиз, какими библиотеками пользоваться?

Comment: Написали, а остальное додумали. А нам придумывать?

Comment: Можно ответить, чтобы вы воспользовались центральной библиотекой в своем городе.

Comment: какой язык программирования? я правльно понял вам нужны длинные числа? и операции над ними?

Comment: Язык C++ и нужны длинные числа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, такая популярная штука [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) (The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library).

Недавно писал одному факторизацию RSA. Он потребовал дельфи, пришлось реализовать это на FGInt.

Comment: Она очень популярная, такая популярная, что гугль выдает тьму не относящейся к делу фигни, не могли бы вы привести ссылку?

Comment: Помогите плиз привязать эту библиотеку к Visual C++ 2010 Express

Comment: какие возникают проблемы?
например тут http://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/ лежит все в компилированном виде и достаточно инструкций на все случаи

Answer (score 1):

[C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/):

> Вы можете использовать эту библиотеку в программах C++, чтобы производить арифметические действия над целыми, размер которых ограничивается только объемом памяти вашего компьютера. Библиотека реализует классы BigUnsigned и BigInteger, которые представляют неотрицательные целые числа и целые числа со знаком соответственно.